Routing on macOS while internet sharing
I got some problems. So Ive connected an MikroTik with openwrt with my laptop over lan. The MikroTik has the ip address 10.10.1.200. I assigned my Mac the ip address 10.10.1.201 on the lan interface. My Mac is connected to the internet via the wifi interface. So with this configuration I got no problems connecting both. I can access via ssh. After I switched "internet sharing" on I can't access any more. I looked at my interfaces and routing tables and the look a little bit weird. I have no route to the subnet 10.10.1.0 any more and my lan interface doesn't have his ip. These are the routing tables when internet sharing is switched on :
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags               Netif Expire
default            (ip address of the wifi interface)     UGScg                 en0
default            link#18            UCSIg           bridge100      !
127                127.0.0.1          UCS                   lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH                    lo0
169.254            link#6             UCS                   en0      !
192.168.2          link#18            UC              bridge100      !

That's not all of the routes, the others are not important. Here is the interface which is normally my lan interface:
en5: flags=8b63<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,ALLMULTI,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=6464<VLAN_MTU,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether a0:ce:c8:c7:68:ef
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
    status: active

The routing table looks like this when internet sharing is off:
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags               Netif Expire
default            (wlan interface ip)      UGScIg                en0
10.10.1/24         link#11            UCS                   en5      !
10.10.1.201/32     link#11            UCS                   en5      !
127                127.0.0.1          UCS                   lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1

The lan interface looks like this:
en5: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=6464<VLAN_MTU,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether a0:ce:c8:c7:68:ef
    inet6 (unimportant)
    inet6 
    inet 10.10.1.201 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.10.1.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
    status: active

